# What's the difference between the "group" and "group-" file?

Tags: etc

I know what the `/etc/group` file is for, but I'm also seeing a `/etc/group-` file. What's the difference between the two?

The same group names and ids appear in both files. Only the last column (users) is different.

I'm running ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Though I cannot find any information in manual pages, I suppose it is a backup copy, as it is documented for `/etc/shadow-` in `shadow` manual page:

```
/etc/shadow-
       Backup file for /etc/shadow.
```