# What's the difference between cat /etc/group and cat /etc/group-

Tags: command-line, etc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the “group” and “group-” file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56036/whats-the-difference-between-the-group-and-group-file)

I just changed a group name and noticed that

```
cat /etc/group
```

Includes the updated group name, but

```
cat /etc/group-
```

includes the old group name.  How are the group and group- files different?

Comment: yes it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a backup file that `groupadd` and similar programs use to store the previous state of the group file.